# ENS function via HTTP provider in web3 doesn't work

Tags: python, web3py

ENS function doesn't work when using web3 package in python virtual env.

```
from web3 import Web3
from ens import ENS

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/[API]'))
w3.isConnected()
```

This returns "True" (i.e. the connection is succesfully being made with my infura provider), but the following function ([exactly the same mentioned in the docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ens_overview.html)) doesn't work:

```
 ns = ENS.fromWeb3(w3)
 address = ns.address('test.eth')

 print(address)
```

`AttributeError: type object 'ENS' has no attribute 'fromWeb3'`

Removing the attribute clears the error, but in VSCode python notebook
on windows, this:

`address = ns.address('test.eth')`

returns "None", regardless of the address.

However, it will work in google colab environment.

Comment: Try updating your ```pip``` version typing ```python -m pip install --ugrapde pip```